# MS DOS digital logic circuit simulation program name

Tags: programming, dos

Once upon a time, about 16 years ago I saw an MS DOS based digital logic circuit program which explains flip-flops, registers, counters, multiplexers, memories etc by simulating circuits. It was simple but instructive.

I searched for the net but I could not find it. Do you remember its name?

Comment: One of [these](http://www.lanet.lv/simtel.net/msdos/electrcl-pre.html)?

Comment: @TomCarpenter thank you for responding. Actually I found that link before I posted my question. There are many packages in the link. I tried `simic104` but it's not what I looked for.